# 2 IP in different subnet/gateway to openVz

Tags: networking, routes, gateway, openvz

I m using debian6 with openVz and got 2 IPs form ISP 61.19.252.68 and 61.19.252.55. After setup bridge and assign .68 to Host-node and .55 to Vz101-node every thing work fine, able to access .55 .68 from outside. But after I got another ip, 61.19.252.191 from IP and assign to Vz102-node then I can't ping or access .191 from any outside network except from Host-node it self. 
Could some one please Help me.

Host-node 61.19.252.68
vz101-node 61.19.252.55
subnet 61.19.252.128 gw 61.19.252.3

vz102-node 61.19.252.191
subnet 61.19.252.128 gw 61.19.252.129

Thank you in advances,
Tomz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.68 & .55 are on different network then .191 so you have to make sure that they know about each other. Are there routes to each other network?

Comment: yes, it's on different router link to both network. .3 to .68,.55 and .129 to .191. My last try is to config host node to .68 and .191 using network bridge (brctl) but it din't work but work for .68 and .55 in same situation. not sure how to set routing or some thing like that, could you please give me suggestion.

Comment: After check with ISP, They were configured wrong gateway to my current network and no router to it.